# How do I allow a user (via cgi/python) to access files on the webserver?

Tags: python, cgi

I have a really good working cgi-bin script written in python right now.  It works like this

1) The engineer will copy a test report folder from a remote linux machine to our main server. (I will automate this by writing a telnet/ssh script?  link to examples appreciated.. where the engineer just plugs in the ip, and the webserver connect to the linux machine and grabs it..)

2) On the main server the engineer will access the cgi script via the webpage and the input is a text-field.  The input given is the http directory of the test report folder (like http://webserver/testreport1/

3) the server takes that input, runs a report and generates some stats (i.e. manager type feedback)

What I want to do is have something like a drop down list for part 2, I know how to do this for uploading files from your local machine, but in this case the files actually are on the webserver, not the engineers computer.  This way he does not have to cut and paste the web directory.  Advice is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python I'd recommend porting your site to django.  Django provides a lot of features you're looking for.

https://www.djangoproject.com/

For part 1, you can allow the engineer to upload files via the site (avoiding any ssh scripting): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

For part 2, there a plenty of jquery plugins for displaying a tree view of the file system you're exposing.  I like jstree: http://www.jstree.com/

Once a report is generated, you can store the results of the report using the django ORM.

Comment: the jstree seemed way overly complicated for what I wanted to do, maybe I just don't know enough javascript... I ended up making my own tree thing based off of this code here http://phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10302144